# how to give different colours to my boxes in html?

Tags: html, r, shiny

P.S. I have updated the post so that it reflects clarity!

how to give different colours to my boxes in html to mark internal and external apps?

I am trying to label the boxes into a different colour as a marking of internal external app. This html then is passed into an rshiny app.

Internal apps are defined by web links that `have astrazeneca` as word inside, and external links are those `without astrazeneca` word.

here is an example of html file I have (I have around 50 html files but will provide only one) for as a sample:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .box {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .box img {
            max-width: 50%;
            height: auto;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .heading {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    
    <h2 class="heading">Gene Expression Analysis</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <a href= "https://rstudio-connect.scp.astrazeneca.net/RStudio_FLAT/", target=”_blank” >
                <img src= "www/FluidigmAnalysisToolkit.v2.png" alt="Box 1">
                <p>Fludigm_Browser</p>
                <p>Perform Fluidigm data analysis</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <a href="https://gtexportal.org/home", target=”_blank”>
                <img src="www/gtex.png" alt="Box 2">
                <p>GTEx Portal</p>
                <p>Gene expression in normal tissue</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <a href="https://azcollaboration.sharepoint.com/sites/AZ208/SitePages/BioTuring.aspx?OR=Teams-HL&CT=1670593304007&clickparam =eyJBcHBOYW1lIjoiVGVhbXMtRGVza3RvcCIsIkFwcFZlcnNpb24iOiIyOC8yMjExMzAwNDEwMCIsIkhhc0ZlZGVyYXRlZFVzZXIiOmZhbHNlfQ%3D%3D", target=”_blank”>
                <img src="www/bioturing.svg" alt="Box 3">
                <p> BioTuring </p>
                <p>Platform for single-cell analysis and spatial transcriptomics exploration</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <a href="http://informatics.medimmune.com/shiny/scope/", target=”_blank”>
                <img src="www/scope.svg" alt="Box 4">
                <p>SCOPE</p>
                <p>Explore available single cell RNA-Seq studies</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 class="heading">Pathway Analysis</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <a href="https://clarivate.com/cortellis/learning/clarivate-for-astrazeneca1796/", target=”_blank”>
                <img src="www/clarivate.png" alt="Box 1">
                <p>Clarivate</p>
                <p>Pathway analysis tools from Cortellis including MetaCore</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <a href="https://analysis.ingenuity.com/pa/launch.jsp">
                <img src= "www/ipa.png" alt="Box 2">
                <p>Ingenuity Pathway Analysis</p>
                <p>Analyze data using manually curated gene sets</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <a href="https://astrazeneca.onramp.bio", target=”_blank”>
                <img src= "www/onramp.png" alt="Box 3">
                <p>OnRamp - Rosalind</p>
                <p>Interactively explore RNA-seq and ChIP-Seq data</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <a href="http://software.broadinstitute.org/gsea/msigdb/index.jsp", target=”_blank”>
                <img src="www/gsea.png" alt="Box 4">
                <p>GSEA</p>
                <p>Gene set enrichment analysis</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see in the above html, I have few links with 'astrazeneca' as word in e.g. `"https://rstudio-connect.scp.astrazeneca.net/RStudio_FLAT/"` and another one without , e.g. "www/bioturing.svg"

This is the rshiny code, for context purposes:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
  theme = shinythemes::shinytheme("united"),

  tags$head(tags$style(".navbar {margin-bottom: 0px;}")),

  tags$head(
    tags$style(".container-fluid {padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;}")
  ),

  navbarPage(
    title = div(
      img(src = "www/bftb_logo_v8_bare.png", height = "30px"),
      "AZ Oncology Bioinformatics Toolbox"
    ),
    windowTitle = "BFTB Landing Page",

    tabPanel("Toolbox", icon = icon("wrench"), disable = TRUE,
             shinydashboard::dashboardPage(
               header = shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(title = "   ", titleWidth = 300, disable = TRUE),
               shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
                 width = 300 ,
                 textInput("search_term", "Search for apps:"),
                 actionButton("search_button", "Search"),
                 shinydashboard::sidebarMenu(
                   shinydashboard::menuItem(
                     "Tools",
                     tabName = "tools_app",
                     icon = icon("wrench")
                   ),
                   shinydashboard::menuSubItem(
                     "Gene Expression/Signature/Pathways",
                     tabName = "gene_app",
                     icon = icon("chart-line")
                   )
                 )
               ),
               shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
                 shinydashboard::tabItems(
                   shinydashboard::tabItem("tools_app", mod_tools_path_ui("tools_path_ui_1")),
                   shinydashboard::tabItem("gene_app", mod_gene_expressions_sign_path_ui("gene_expression_sign_path_ui"))
                 )
               )
             )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output){


}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And the 2 modules: tools one

```
mod_tools_path_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    
  )
}
```

and the gene one:

```
  mod_gene_expressions_sign_path_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    shinydashboard::tabItem(
      tabName = "gene_app",
      fluidRow(
        shiny::headerPanel(h3()),
        br(),
        htmltools::htmlTemplate("www/gene.html")
      )
    )
  )
  
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? And it's strange to use `shinydashboard` inside a `navbarPage`.

Comment: How strange it is ? As long as it works, why that is strange?

Comment: Normally we use `shinydashboardPage` at the top level. That's fine if it works but this is not a standard way of usage. And this is hard to read (for me at least).

Comment: Well, firstly, that doesn’t really answer the question. I did not ask any correction around the main code? I clearly asked for a solution that isn’t even related to what you address.

Comment: A comment is... a comment! Not an answer.

Comment: And I have another comment: you have a strange way to ask questions. You post a one-kilometer long question, don't do any effort to minimize it, you post an empty Shiny module totally useless, and you use a somehow agressive tone in the comments.

Comment: hey Stephane, I am sorry if I have been coming across like that. I did not mean to come across like it. I believe it did not make sense to comment on a code that already worked, as I thought it would not be a problem the code itself. So that is why I found your comment a bit aggressive as well. And I believe what you mention above is linked to the another post, where I haven't got a proper answer and I have been blamed when I asked whether you've tried the reproducible example. However, I thank you for the above answer. I need to try it on my code yet haven't done it due the servers being down

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I am sorry but wanted to explain clearly what I  wanted to express. Sometimes giving a bit of background helps?

Comment: and yes, I have changed the question and made it shorter, I am hoping this time is good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the question (not sure), you are asking for the CSS to set different colors to some links.

You can use two classes for the `a` tags:

```html
        <div class="box">
            <a class="internal" href="https://rstudio-connect.scp.astrazeneca.net/RStudio_FLAT/" target=”_blank”>
                <img src="www/FluidigmAnalysisToolkit.v2.png" alt="Box 1">
                <p>Fludigm_Browser</p>
                <p>Perform Fluidigm data analysis</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <a class="external" href="https://gtexportal.org/home" target=”_blank”>
                <img src="www/gtex.png" alt="Box 2">
                <p>GTEx Portal</p>
                <p>Gene expression in normal tissue</p>
            </a>
        </div>
```

then use such CSS:

```css
        a.internal:link {
            color: green;
            background-color: transparent;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a.internal:visited {
            color: pink;
            background-color: transparent;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a.internal:hover {
            color: red;
            background-color: transparent;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        a.internal:active {
            color: yellow;
            background-color: transparent;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        a.external:link {
            color: crimson;
            background-color: transparent;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a.external:visited {
            color: cyan;
            background-color: transparent;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a.external:hover {
            color: midnightblue;
            background-color: transparent;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        a.external:active {
            color: lime;
            background-color: transparent;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
```

You should be careful with the class names such as `container` and `box` because it's possible they are already used in Shiny(dashboard).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .box {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .box img {
            max-width: 50%;
            height: auto;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .heading {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 50px;
        }

        a.internal:link {
            color: green;
            background-color: transparent;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a.internal:visited {
            color: pink;
            background-color: transparent;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a.internal:hover {
            color: red;
            background-color: transparent;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        a.internal:active {
            color: yellow;
            background-color: transparent;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        a.external:link {
            color: crimson;
            background-color: transparent;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a.external:visited {
            color: cyan;
            background-color: transparent;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a.external:hover {
            color: midnightblue;
            background-color: transparent;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        a.external:active {
            color: lime;
            background-color: transparent;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h2 class="heading">Gene Expression Analysis</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <a class="internal" href="https://rstudio-connect.scp.astrazeneca.net/RStudio_FLAT/" target=”_blank”>
                <img src="www/FluidigmAnalysisToolkit.v2.png" alt="Box 1">
                <p>Fludigm_Browser</p>
                <p>Perform Fluidigm data analysis</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <a class="external" href="https://gtexportal.org/home" target=”_blank”>
                <img src="www/gtex.png" alt="Box 2">
                <p>GTEx Portal</p>
                <p>Gene expression in normal tissue</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```